# Using Jenkins to clone a Git Repository with multiple Submodules

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I have Jenkins (2.54) running with the Git plugin (3.2.0).  I am trying to clone a repo from Stash with multiple Submodules in it.  When I try to clone this repo, Jenkins will create the top folder with the submodule name, but then it will hang and not clone anything inside of them.

The inside of the repo looks like this -

```
submodule1
submodule2
submodule3
submodule4
```

Jenkins will create 4 folders in the workspace that have the same name as the submodules, but then it will hang.  Each one of these folders will be empty.

I have tried setting a shallow depth clone of 1, and checking "Recursively Update Submodules", but the Jenkins job will still hang after creating these empty folders.

Does anyone have any idea what I could do to get these submodules to be cloned by Jenkins correctly?  It seems as if they are not being recursively cloned by Jenkins.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it as simple as you can. Try to trigger another jobs (one for every submodule - so it should be 4 jobs) and fetch (or clone) from git to submodules directories. Job for every submodule will be simple job, but which triggered by main job. You need only to specify the $WORKSPACE with suitable directory. 
In General tab click the "advanced" button and in the choose the "Use custom workspace" option. Then fill the Directory field with path to your submodule folder: 
$JENKINS_HOME/-Path-to-main-job-/-Path-to-submodule

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riE2y.png)